# MVC - How to add css property on dropdown based on condition

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I started using MVC after a long time and now I am unable to do some things really easy.

Model class:

```
public class TaskDetails
{
    public string ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EstimatedDate { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
List<SelectListItem> query = DE.tblEmployees
                               .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.Name, Value = c.Name })
                               .ToList();
ViewBag.Categories = query;
return View();
```

View:

```
<div class="dropdown">
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Categories, "--User Name--")
</div>
```

This is the source and its working perfectly, but what I want to do is to hide all specific options in dropdown where `Value != NewTask`

Comment: What is `NewTask` ?

Comment: Text = c.Name, Value = c.Name are you sure ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure is solution for you, but just in case.

```
 List<SelectListItem> query = DE.tblEmployees
    .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.ProjectName, Value = c.ProjectName })
    .Where(x => x.Value.Equals("NewTask"))
    .ToList();
```

Or in view directly:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", ((List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Categories).Where(x => x.Value.Equals("NewTask")), "--User Name--")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you want to show in your dropdown the ProjectIDs which are greater than 10, right?

You can do that at your controller,

```
DE.tblEmployees.Select(c => new SelectItem
                      {Text = c.Name, Value = c.Name }).Where(x => x.ProjectID > 10).ToList();
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Have you answered the right question?  Sorry, after looking more, you have - just don't know where you are getting the specific project ids > 10 bit from (unless question was edited and edit hasn't shown up)

Comment: Sorry, I added that first by mistake please see update